# Relative paths not recognized in Yeoman AngularJS Eclipse project

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, yeoman, relative-path

I have created an Angular project using Yeoman. I want to use Eclipse 4.5.1 (Mars.1) as my IDE. 
Project structure:

```
project
--- app
   --- assets
      --- css
      --- img
          --- yeoman.png
   --- modules
      --- main
          --- main.html
          --- mainCtrl.js
   --- index.html
   --- ... (other files/folders)
--- bower_components
--- ... (other files/folders)
```

I've added AngularJS Eclipse plugin, but one thing is not working correctly: I have problems with file relative paths, e.g.:

Undefined Image file in main.html

```
<img src="assets/img/yeoman.png" alt="I'm Yeoman">
```

Undefined JavaScript file in index.html for each JS file from bower_components folder and for external script:

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
...
<script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'></script>
```

Undefined CSS file in index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

In the browser everything works fine, but I want to get rid of error markers in eclipse. I can turn them off in project properties -> Web Resources -> Validation, but it does not solve my case, because firstly I would like to keep link validation and secondly CSS classes from bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css are not recognized in eclipse. I know that I can manually change path to ../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css and so on, but after each grunt build they will be restored, and adding new dependencies (grunt install --save component_name) will require some manual changes, too.

Comment: I don't understand why your Eclipse project structure is not the same than your WebBrowser project structure?

Comment: It is the way that yeoman generate project. I've moved manually "bower_components" folder under "app" folder and modified path to bower components in .bowerrc.json file. Now it is working.